# Check if at least one key in array starts with character

Tags: php

I have an array with terms and definitions>

```
$myArray = array("apple" => "Fruit that grows ...", "car" => "Vehicle on four...");
```

How do I determine if I have words starting with a particular letter? Say, "c" for car?

I need to do this check with JS if possible, without reloading the page.

Comment: This looks like php not javascript.

Comment: Is that JavaScript? If it is some server side script.. then do a view source on the webpage and post the rendered value.

Comment: It's a combo. Some of it in PHP, but I need to check on click without reloading the page.

Comment: @santa Post the rendered final code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate and check yourself:

```
foreach( $myArray as $key=>$val ) {
   if( $key[0] == 'c' ) {
     // bingo
   }
}
```